# Thousands of 4776 Events on Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, security

We have thousands of 4776 Events on our domain controller. All events show 3 workstations name - randomly and use same user account name - our domain name.

Domain controller had RDP enabled and was accessible from outside. We changed the port after seeing these alerts. But these events continue.

Any suggestion on how to track source and fix this.
Thanks

Comment: We don't all have every Event ID memorized, so please post the details of the event.

Answer (score 0):

These events indicate a logon using NTLM, the source of the authentications would be the "Source Workstation" in the event. Check the workstations to see if an application is authenticating repeatedly. You should be able to take the workstations mentioned offline and no longer see these events.